# Javascript console.log causes page functionality to change

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, console.log

I have a function which modifies the innerHTML of the control in which the text is being written.

A reproduction of the function:

```
function handleInput(element, fontName, fontSize) {

    //Code segment 1...

    console.log(elementNode.innerHTML + (elementNode.parentNode ? ", en.pn.ih: " + elementNode.parentNode.innerHTML : ""));

    //Code segment 2....

    var arrayFont = elementNode.getElementsByTagName("font");
    for (var j = 0; j < arrayFont.length; j++)     //Multiple or single <FONT> tag withint a <P> tag
    {

        //Code segment 3...

        console.log("*** 3: Before: fn.ih: " + fontNode.innerHTML + (fontNode.parentNode ? ", fn.pn.ih: " + fontNode.parentNode.innerHTML : ""));

        //Code segment 4...

        console.log("*** 3: After: fn.ih: " + fontNode.innerHTML + (fontNode.parentNode ? ", fn.pn.ih: " + fontNode.parentNode.innerHTML : ""));
    }
}
```

In code segments 3 and 4, I'm modifying the innerHTML of both `elementNode` and `fontNode`. These changes take effect only if the `console.log` is executed. If I comment out the `console.log` operations, the changes made in segments 3 and 4 cause unwanted non-breaking-spaces and newlines (I'm inserting the newline through code).

Why is this happening?

Comment: @Rajesh, the code I'm writing is targeted only for IE10, IE11.

Comment: Can you show us some working example to debug?

Comment: i've had comparable issues when functions run asynchronously: does f.e. code segment 4 start running before code segment 3 is finished? A simple console.log like you have may provide for the millisecond needed to finish the first function. So if this is the case you may need to rewrite the functions to prevent this from happening. Anyway as titi23 says, it'll help if you provide all code.